# Small Location Change Detection

Tags: iphone, gps, location

I'm need to detect small location change for the iphone , I tried the sample that's called Locate Me, but it doesn't recognize the small change in the location. Is there any way for doing this?

Thanks in Advance.

Best regards
John

Comment: GPS accuracy is not that precise -- could you maybe use the accelerometer instead?

Comment: How much accuracy you want? GPS does a nice job in locating a user when location accuracy is set to best.

Comment: @Justin, how could i use the Accelerometer to determine the distance?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were looking for actual physical location, or just something like the user moving the phone back and forth.  For the second, you may be able to use the accelerometer.  In general, you can integrate the acceleration vector twice to get position, but there are a couple of problems: gravity and velocity issues (knowing rest velocity, using the app in a car, etc).  You might be able to compensate these to get a rough estimate of distance, though.

Answer (score 0):

How small is the change that you expected?

Maybe you should set the accuracy to it's maximum and calculate the displacement on the delegate method.

Configure the location manager to give you it's best.

```
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:0.0];
```

And then on the delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    // Calculate the distance between the two locations
    CGFloat distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];

    if (distance >= MIN_DISPLACEMENT) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

To get more accurate data from the location manager, set the proper keys for [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) (location-services, gps) on the Info.plist.

Comment: i tried this solution, but i need the distance to be updated in the real time, GPS requires time to get the distance travelled which is not suitable in my app.

Comment: @John, if you need real time updates you would need to take advantage of the accelerometer or (on iOS4) http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW26