# Detect small changes in Location

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, gps, core-location

How can i detect small location change for the iphone? In my application i need to detect small location changes like *2 cm or 5 cm*. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388062/small-location-change-detection). But those answers not helping me.

Comment: What kind of movement? Where? What other things do you have available in the area?

Comment: I need to detect even a shake if possible. I need to do this in background. So i can use only gps.

Comment: Using GPS you're lucky if you can get 5 meters, nevermind 5 cm. Really. The GPS on iPhone is not very accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't. The GPS does not provide sub-meter accuracy.

You could use Core Motion to detect changes in acceleration, which might or might not meet your needs, but if the phone is moving at a constant velocity you would not sense it, and you would not be able to convert the accelerometer data into position data with any reliability.